# What could be causing this runtime Lexer error in ANTLR4 4.7.1?

Tags: antlr4

I am trying to update to ANTLR4 4.7.1 from 4.5. Aside from environment, the only change has been to update ANTLRInputStream and ANTLRFileStream references to CharStreams. Yet the code that worked in 4.5 now throws an error.

After the updates, I get a NoSuchMethod error when I try to run a test.

```
$ /usr/bin/java -cp $classpath org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig com.greg.gumji_parser.Gumji2001 source_text -tokens -tree gumji/test_debug4.v
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.RuleTransition.<init>(Lorg/antlr/v4/runtime/atn/RuleStartState;IILorg/antlr/v4/runtime/atn/ATNState;)V
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNDeserializer.edgeFactory(ATNDeserializer.java:715)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNDeserializer.deserialize(ATNDeserializer.java:332)
    at com.greg.gumji_parser.Gumji2001Lexer.<clinit>(Gumji2001Lexer.java:3485)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.process(TestRig.java:144)
    at org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.main(TestRig.java:119)
$ echo $classpath
/home/greg/.m2/repository/com/greg/gumji2001-parser/1.0-SNAPSHOT/*:/usr/local/share/java/*:/home/greg/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr4/4.7.1/antlr4-4.7.1.jar:/home/greg/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.7.1/antlr4-runtime-4.7.1.jar
```

Has the ATN become too large? I would appreciate any advice on how to approach debugging this.

Comment: The fact you're using wildcards for your imports may lead to importing unintended dependencies (eg from `/usr/local/share/java`, or maybe from that snapshot folder); it those paths contain older antlr versions, you may actually be using an older versions of the runtime than you think you're using, or worse: a combination of new and old!

Comment: Thanks! I had slung the classpath together manually for debug purposes. When I rationalized it without wildcards, no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by [Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel) in comments above:

> The fact you're using wildcards for your imports may lead to importing
>   unintended dependencies (eg from `/usr/local/share/java`, or maybe
>   from that snapshot folder); it those paths contain older antlr
>   versions, you may actually be using an older versions of the runtime
>   than you think you're using, or worse: a combination of new and old!